# Standardizing data from different distributions

Tags: normalization

I have energy data from different homes (~200), and I wish to merge all the energy data to create a combined dataset.

Since the individual homes have different power consumption, I get different distributions for every house. What will be the ideal strategy for normalizing the dataset?

The original energy data distribution of individual homes show lognormal characteristics.

[image: Original Energy Data shows a lognormal distribution]

Using log transform the energy distributions resembles mixtures of Gaussians.

[image: Transformed distribution]

Comment: what is your goal after building a combined data set ?